# PHP Warning: Use of undefined constant PASSWORD_ARGON2ID when using password_hash() in php 7.3

Tags: php, php-7.3, php-password-hash, argon2-ffi

I recently installed PHP 7.3.6 through Plesk's web GUI for a development copy of a web app, as I intend to update our production environment from php 7.0 to 7.3. I decided to take the opportunity to upgrade our password hashing from PBKDF2 to Argon2ID since the PHP core has it already included. I was surprised to get a warning stating that the PASSWORD_ARGON2ID constant is undefined, since I understand it was added in php 7.3.0.

I tried searching for any instance of this error and the only thing I found that was relevant was this undetailed post in a Laravel forum:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/use-of-undefined-constant-password-argon2id-assumed-password-argon2id?page=1

The application is hosted on a shared vps with MediaTemple. Centos 7, using nginx as a reverse proxy over Apache. It is a subdomain for development running 7.3.6 along side the main domain which is running the production version of the app, 7.0.33.

```
$this->password = password_hash('password123', PASSWORD_ARGON2ID, array('time_cost' => 10, 'memory_cost' => '2048k', 'threads' => 6));
```

I expected the PASSWORD_ARGON2ID constant to be defined but it was reported as undefined:

```
Use of undefined constant PASSWORD_ARGON2ID - assumed 'PASSWORD_ARGON2ID' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

Comment: *This algorithm is only available if PHP has been compiled with Argon2 support.* - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use the Argon2 algorithm with password\_hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47602044/how-do-i-use-the-argon2-algorithm-with-password-hash)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*This algorithm is only available if PHP has been compiled with Argon2 support.* - [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

If you want to use it whenever it is available, I would recommend to check with `defined` or else fallback to a default algorithm.

```
if(defined('PASSWORD_ARGON2ID')) {
    $hash = password_hash('password123', PASSWORD_ARGON2ID, array('time_cost' => 10, 'memory_cost' => '2048k', 'threads' => 6));
} else {
    $hash = password_hash('password123', PASSWORD_DEFAULT, array('time_cost' => 10, 'memory_cost' => '2048k', 'threads' => 6));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I assumed Plesk would have compiled PHP with Argon2 support by the time they released 7.3 but I guess that's not the case. Anyone using Plesk to install / upgrade PHP will not have the option to use Argon2 unless they recompile PHP 7.2/7.3 with the option --with-password-argon2

Comment: +1 well, this is a good solution if someone did not want to stuck and waste time in installing aragon2i.

Comment: can confirm that you need at least PHP 7.3 to have Argon2 support

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get rid of the warning by installing module sodium.

debian / ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install php-sodium`

centos/rhel: `sudo yum install php-sodium`

Comment: This didn't work for me, after installing php-sodium still complaining about PASSWORD_ARGON2ID

Comment: I finally solved it by using 7.1 as I do not really need updating to 7.3 by now, thanks